# Bot is not responding in web chat after publishing it using visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, bots, azure-bot-service, bot-framework-composer

I have created one bot in composer. Created all required services (App service, QnA Maker, LUIS, Web App Bot). I have added LUIS Configuration value (key and endpoint). Added QnA Maker key also. My bot is working fine Remotely.
I have given Microsoft AppId & Password in Appsettings.JSON .
I published the bot using Visual Studio. It got published successfully.
When I tried to test it from azure portal using test in web chat, it is not responding.
I am getting the error "**There was an error sending this message to your bot: HTTP status code InternalServerError**".
How to check the internal error and how I can fix that?
Thanks in advance.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6ey1.png)

Answer (score 0):

Composer performs several tasks to prepare and build your bot files when publishing it that VS might not do. If building and deploying the bot through Visual Studio is not working, you could try the command line method, or just stick with Composer's own publish utility.

Comment: Thanks for the replyCan you please send documentation for command line publish with Qna Maker and LUIS. I have found only normal one (without QNA, KB, LUIS).

Comment: I don't understand. [Deploy your bot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-deploy-az-cli?view=azure-bot-service-4.0) is the method. It might not work because it's a Composer bot, but you can try.